# How to prevent deletion of a student who has payment due?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a University Management Project where I am trying to write a condition to prevent a user to in deleting a Student who has Payment due in his/her account.

[image]

Like if I want to delete the student named Abby John, I should not be able to because she has a payment due of $50. But with the code I am trying to write, it gets deleted without any error message/warning.

I edited the *POST Delete* method in the **StudentController**, but it's not working. Any tips or help please, kindly.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            Student s = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);

            if (s.PaymentDue > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Student has overdue payment. Need to CLEAR payment before deletion!";
            }
            try
            {
                Student student = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
                studentRepository.DeleteStudent(id);
                studentRepository.Save();
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
                return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

// GET: /Student/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(bool? saveChangesError = false, int id = 0)
        {
            if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Delete failed. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.";
            }
            Student student = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
            return View(student);
        }
```

Comment: You just assign value to `ErrorMessage`... surround the `try/catch` with `else{}` statement or return in `if`

Comment: Your `try` block is going to still get executed even if your `ViewBag.ErrorMessage` is set with the current logic.  So your server-side validation doesn't do much.  On the client-size, you can just use a conditional in your razor to not show delete if there's a value there.

Comment: Okay, I surrounded the `try/catch` statement with an `else{}` and it works by not deleting the student. But it doesn't show the error message as to why it did not delete. It just goes back to the Students list page.

Comment: @Truecolor, Stop redirecting. you will loose the error message. Show the action that is mapped to the students page. Here is the flow. when hit delete action validate your conditions. if validation fails create error and let action flow to completeion making sure to populate what was in the original view. otherwise do what you were doing before.

Comment: As @stephen.vakil mentioned on the answer below, the `ViewBag` contents are lost here due to the redirect.

Comment: @Truecolor, Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't do anything with the `ErrorMessage` logic, you could do something like this:

```
var paymentDue = false;
if (s.PaymentDue > 0)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Student has overdue payment. Need to CLEAR payment before deletion!";
    paymentDue = true;
}

if(!paymentDue)
{
    try
    {
        Student student = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
        studentRepository.DeleteStudent(id);
        studentRepository.Save();
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
        return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });
    }
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: I think your logic is reversed.  I think you meant `if(!paymentDue)`

Comment: You're absolutely right @ChrisDunaway, I fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: the `ViewBag` data will get lost here because of the redirect.

Comment: That would happen regardless using redirects though, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the code to delete the student even after failing on your business logic. If you use `RedirectToAction`, you will lose your `ViewBag` data. This would be a simple way to return to the same view after populating your `ViewBag.ErrorMessage` value:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    Student s = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);

    if (s.PaymentDue > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Student has overdue payment. Need to CLEAR payment before deletion!";
        // Assuming that you are using Student object to populate your delete view
        return View(s);
    }

    try
    {
        Student student = studentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
        studentRepository.DeleteStudent(id);
        studentRepository.Save();
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.
        return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Without knowing how the original view was populated this will also fail.

Comment: @Nkosi True. He needs to pass model/value in the View that is used to populate the view.

Comment: I tried `return View();` instead of `RediredtToAction` and it takes me to a page where it shows the Error Message, but still shows "Are you sure you want to delete this?" And then I have to click the Back to List to go back to the Students page.        Would it help to post my full View for _Delete.cshtml_ ?

Comment: What are you using for delete get action? If it's an instance of Student object, then you can use `return View(s);` instead. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, I used `return View(s)` and it is taking me to a second duplicate page with the error message showing. But now I my Edit method doesn't work. One thing or the other! Thanks for the help.